# How to disable the "beep" on Lenovo P1 gen 2 with Manjaro (Arch)?

Tags: bios, arch-linux, lenovo-laptop, manjaro

I'm running Manjaro I3 (ArchiLinux based) on my Lenovo P1 gen 2.

All works well, but the computer is beeping to much:

- It beeps when I close the laptop.
- It beeps when I lock the screen.
- It beeps regularly if the computed is not being used.

This is kind of annoying and the only workaround I found is to disable the sound globally.

How can I disable the beeps only? Is is something to do on the BIOS or is it related to the OS?

Comment: I have a Lenovo X1 and looked at the P1 specs. It seems similar. My laptop does not beep on Lock, does not beep on Suspend (Lid close), and does not beep when Idle (not being used).  Windows 10 Pro.   So I am quite sure this is your operating system. I am working in Kali right now and it does not beep except when I click the icon to shut it down

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have any Lenovo XYZ around me. But I know that on my machines (Arch Linux), I have to remove the `pcspkr` (PC Speaker) kernel module in order to remove the "beep".

To look if it's loaded:

```
# lsmod | grep pcspkr
```

To unload it (temporary) to see if the "beep" is gone:

```
# rmmod pcspkr
```

If it is the solution to your problem, you have to blacklist it in order to prevent it from being loaded on boot.

That means:

```
# echo "blacklist pcspkr" > /etc/modprobe.d/nobeep.conf
```

Note: The name of the file can be whatever you want as long as it is located inside the `/etc/modprobe.d` directory.

If it does not solve your problem that means that one of the following control the "beep":

- BIOS
- Desktop Environment
- Other installed modules, software ... (can be anything)

I wrote this directly but [the documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PC_speaker) should explain things better than me.

Comment: This is a quite radical solution, but it works. Thanks!